# Display right column above left without absolute positioning

Tags: css

I have two columns: .group-left and .group-right. On mobile, I want the right column to be displayed above the left. The code below displays the right column below the left on mobile devices. The height of the right column is variable so I don't think I can use absolute positioning. Is there another way to accomplish this with CSS?

```
@media all and (min-width: 980px) {
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-left {
    width: 47% !important;
    min-width:320px;
  }
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-right {
    width: 48%;
    min-width:320px;
    float:right;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 979px) {
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-left {
    width: 95%;
    min-width:300px;
  }
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-right {
    width: 95%;
    min-width:300px;
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the html look like, i suspect you have the columns in the wrong order

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your divs are in the right order (group-left on top)

```
<div class="node-type-new-donate-page">
    <div class="group-left">go left</div>
    <div class="group-right">go right</div>
</div>
```

Then add `float:left` to `.group-left` for your `min-width 980px;`

```
@media all and (min-width: 980px) {
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-left {
    width: 47% !important;
    min-width:320px;
    float:left;
  }
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-right {
    width: 48%;
    min-width:320px;
    float:right;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 979px) {
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-left {
    width: 95%;
    min-width:300px;
  }
  .node-type-new-donate-page .group-right {
    width: 95%;
    min-width:300px;
  }
}
```

depending on your layout you might need to use clearfix on your `.node-type-new-donate-page`